# problem changing texture from one to another

Tags: unity, c#

I have a problem that, when exceeding the maximum or minimum texture in the matrix, is giving this error, what can I do?

**IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.**

```
    public void previous(){
    currentTexture--;
    shouldChange = false;
}

public void next()
{
    currentTexture++;
    shouldChange = true;
}

void Update()
{
    if (texture.Length == 2)
        return;
    if (texture.Length == 0)
        return;
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Length; i++)
                arrays[i].material.mainTexture = texture[currentTexture];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

An `IndexOutOfRange` exception is an exception that is thrown when an attempt is made to access an element of an array or collection with an index that is outside its bounds (index < 0 or >= length of the array)

You need to make sure your `currentTexture` does not go outside those bounds. Here is a solution to make the `currentTexture` loop (of value was supposed to go below 0, it will take the value `length - 1`, if the value was supposed to go over `length - 1`, it will have a value of `0`)

```
public void previous()
{
    currentTexture = (currentTexture + texture.Length - 1) % texture.Length;
    shouldChange = false;
    SetTexture();
}

public void next()
{
    currentTexture = (currentTexture + 1) % texture.Length;
    shouldChange = true;
    SetTexture();
}

private void SetTexture()
{
    if (texture.Length == 2 || texture.Length == 0)
        return;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Length; i++)
        arrays[i].material.mainTexture = texture[currentTexture];
}

/*
// Remove this unnecessary Update
void Update()
{
    if (texture.Length == 2)
        return;
    if (texture.Length == 0)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Length; i++)
        arrays[i].material.mainTexture = texture[currentTexture];
}
*/
```